# Edit Comments Fields

Tags: comments, comment-form

I need to edit the comments fields.

1 - The metadata should be only date;
2 - The comment itself should be trimmed;
3 - the word 'says' next to the name should be gone;

I believe I can manage the logics, however I do not know how to get these fields, apply the logic, and return them.

[image]

```
<article id="div-comment-5" class="comment-body">
    <footer class="comment-meta">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <img alt="" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/710dade4711ee07ca27e7db85255b701?s=50&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/710dade4711ee07ca27e7db85255b701?s=100&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-50 photo" height="50" width="50" loading="lazy" />                      
            <b class="fn">
                <a href="http://mundo.local" rel="external nofollow ugc" class="url">
                    Stefano Monteiro
                </a>
            </b> 
            <span class="says">says:</span>                 
        </div><!-- .comment-author -->
        <div class="comment-metadata">
            <a href="http://mundo.local/videos/music-classic-canada-37/#comment-5">
                <time datetime="2021-01-21T17:59:16+00:00">January 21, 2021 at 5:59 pm</time>
            </a> 
            <span class="edit-link">
                <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://mundo.local/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&amp;c=5">Edit</a>
            </span>                 
        </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->
    </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->
    <div class="comment-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div><!-- .comment-content -->
    <div class="reply">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="http://mundo.local/videos/music-classic-canada-37/?replytocom=5#respond" data-commentid="5" data-postid="830" data-belowelement="div-comment-5" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="Reply to Stefano Monteiro" aria-label="Reply to Stefano Monteiro">Reply</a>
    </div>  
</article>
```

Comment: Where does the code you show come from? is this a template in your current theme or a partial.. give some more information and explain what you tried and what issues you had?

Comment: The code comes from the theme (Elementor). The code is what that image is made of. My question is how I can edit this comments HTML.

Comment: Did you ask this question on the Elementor forum? The WP way would be to use filters or a child theme, both could work.

Comment: That's what I am looking for, filters.

Comment: There are no obvious filters in the template you have included, so you might need to ask on the Elemnetor forum, read their documentation or learn how to create a child them - if you don't already - and how this enables you to edit template files more easily.